# AngularJs with NodeJs cannt access angular services in directive link function

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create Angular.js directive written using NodeJS , and want to use external angular services like $parse in directive link function   I cannot access injected services its undefined. Help me please to do it. Here is my directive:

```
'use strict';

var ngMatch = function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict :'AE',
    link: link,
    require: '?ngModel'

  }
};

/** @ngInject */
function link(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
// if ngModel is not defined, we don't need to do anything
if (!ctrl) return;
if (!attrs['ngMatch']) return;

var firstPassword = $parse(attrs['ngMatch']);

var validator = function (value) {
var temp = firstPassword(scope),
v = value === temp;
ctrl.$setValidity('match', v);
return value;
}

ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);
ctrl.$formatters.push(validator);
attrs.$observe('ngMatch', function () {
validator(ctrl.$viewValue);
});

}
ngMatch.$inject =['$parse'];

module.exports = ngMatch;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Best not to use ngMatch. You will have name space collisions if Angular decided to have a built in ngMatch directive
- You have just defined two objects ngMatch and link. There is no way angular would know that ngMatch is a directive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but angular know that ngMatch is a directive , Otherwise I would not have received the error with the $parse.